# Convertir número a texto sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Estoy haciendo una consulta a una bbdd en **sqlite** para que me devuelva el trackid,cancion y la duración pero me piden que la duración sea corta, media o larga dependiendo del número, consigo sacar el trackid, las canciones y las duraciones pero no consigo que el campo duración que es un int se muestre como una cadena de texto

Yo estoy ejecutando la siguiente query:

```
SELECT TrackId, Name as [cancion], Milliseconds as [duracion] FROM tracks;
```

Y me saca esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento usar `select cast(Milliseconds as text) from tracks;` pero me lo devuelve vacío

Alguna idea??

Gracias de antemano

Comment: que intestas hacer o cual es el resultado esperado?

Comment: Hola, lo que quiero es la misma tabla que me devuelve pero en duración si es menor de 120000 milisegundos sea corta, entre 120000 y 30000 sea media y si es superior a 3000 sea larga

Comment: puedes hacerlo utilizanco la clausula `CASE` de sql https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Me ha servido al a perfección, estoy empezando con SQL y no sabía que se podía hacer un if como en python y demás!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer esto:

```
SELECT TrackId, Name as [cancion], 
CASE
WHEN [duracion] < 120000 THEN 'corta' 
WHEN [duracion] < 30000 THEN 'media' 
ELSE 'larga'
END AS duracion FROM tracks;
```

El **CASE** es igual como un **IF** dentro de una consulta